# Locust tests returning infrequent short bursts of "502: Bad Gateway" errors

Tags: python, locust, http-status-code-502

I'm running locust tests in Python to test an API endpoint. For some reason, I am getting short spikes of `502 Sever Error: Bad Gateway` responses intermittently. Has anyone else had this issue? I've attached a graph from Locust showing the pattern of 502 errors, which occur ~1% of the time.

[RPS rate on Locust](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qh7J5.png)

I am using closed connections with multiple concurrent users.

Comment: Is API responsive without Locust?

Comment: Yes, I've never seen a 502 (or any 500-error) on calls I've made or calls users have made.

Answer (score 0):

Your target server/reverse proxy/load balancer/something is responding with that error. Try to trace the error on that side, this is not coming from Locust itself.